# How to run kafka s3 sink connector in confluent 6.2.0

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, s3-kafka-connector

Have installed **confluent 6.2.0** in my 3 kafka nodes and also installed **confluentinc-kafka-connect-s3-10.0.1** in 3 nodes and modified the **quickstart-s3.properties** but not sure how to start that...

Answer (score 0):

Same answer applies without Confluent Platform.

You'd run one of the included `bin/connect-*` scripts to start a Connect worker.

The quickstart file is only applicable for standalone mode.